# Fetching list of objects from API react native

Tags: json, react-native, api

im trying to print times from below api but api is nested.

The Api data is :
{
"code": 200,
"status": "OK",
"results": {
"datetime": [
{
"times": {
"Imsak": "03:57",
"Sunrise": "05:31",
"Fajr": "04:07",
"Dhuhr": "12:10",
"Asr": "15:50",
"Sunset": "18:49",
"Maghrib": "19:00",
"Isha": "20:13",
"Midnight": "23:28"
},
"date": {
"timestamp": 1598140800,
"gregorian": "2020-08-23",
"hijri": "1442-01-04"
}
}
],
"location": {
"latitude": 33.729389190673828,
"longitude": 73.093147277832031,
"elevation": 585.0,
"city": "Islamabad",
"country": "Pakistan",
"country_code": "PK",
"timezone": "Asia/Karachi",
"local_offset": 5.0
},
"settings": {
"timeformat": "HH:mm",
"school": "Ithna Ashari",
"juristic": "Shafii",
"highlat": "None",
"fajr_angle": 18.0,
"isha_angle": 18.0
}
}
}

I want to display all the prayers times using ToucableOpacity in React-native

Fetching class is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

class tryo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            timings: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        fetch("https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/today.json?city=islamabad", {
            "method": "GET",

        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log("Mount",responseJson);
                this.setState({
                    timings: responseJson.results
                })
                console.log("state check",this.state.timings)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }


    render() {






   const data=this.state.timings
        console.log("lets check data",this.state.timings)
        return (
// <View>
//  <Text>dsd</Text>
// </View>

            <View style={styles.container}>

                {Object.entries(data).map((item,index)=>(
                    <TouchableOpacity key={index} style={styles.touch_sense} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}  >

                        <Text style={styles.item_Text} >

                            {item['times']}

                        </Text>

                    </TouchableOpacity>

                )   )
                }

             </View>

        );}
}
export default tryo

const styles=StyleSheet.create({

        item_Text:{
            fontWeight:'bold',
            fontSize: 20,


        },
        container:{

            // textAlign:'center',
            // alignItems:'center',
            // justifyContent:'center',
            // marginTop:15,
            padding:5,
            // backgroundColor:'green'

        }
        ,
        touch_sense:{
            textAlign: 'center',
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems:'center',
            marginTop:10,
            backgroundColor:'#1FE884',
            width:400,
            height:80


        }



    }

);
```

i want to access attributes of times from the APi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an additional render method, like this:

```
renderTimes(times) {
    return times.map( (time) => {
        <Text style={styles.item_Text}>
            {time}
        </Text>
    });
}
```

and then update your render method to be:

```
render() {
    return ( 
        <View style={styles.container}>
            { Object.entries(data).map((item,index)=>(
                <TouchableOpacity key={index} style={styles.touch_sense} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}  >
                    {renderTimes(item['times'])}
                </TouchableOpacity>
             )}
         </View>
    );
}
```

If you want each time to be its own `TouchableOpacity`, just refactor those lines of code into that `renderTimes` method.